# Trying to skip 1 run of a do/while loop in C

Tags: c, loops, do-while

I know this is probably really simple but I just can't get it to work. I'm trying to write a program which counts backwards from 15 to 1 using a do/while loop. However, I also have to NOT print when the counter gets to 11, so the output looks like 15, 13, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1. I know I need to use a continue/break somewhere with my if statement, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

int doWhileCount = 15;

do {

    printf("%d\n", doWhileCount);
    doWhileCount = doWhileCount -2;

    if (doWhileCount == 11) {
        continue;
    }


} while (doWhileCount >= 1);


}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks guys! (Sorry again for the simple as hell problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `if` statement *before* the print statement. Otherwise, your `continue;` is skipping nothing.

```
do {
    doWhileCount = doWhileCount -2;

    if (doWhileCount == 11) {
        continue;
    }

    printf("%d\n", doWhileCount);

} while (doWhileCount >= 1);
```

Note that this will require you to set `doWhileCount` to `17` initially.

Alternatively, just use the `if` statement (which doesn't require you to set `doWhileCount` to `17`):

```
do {
    if (doWhileCount != 11) {
        printf("%d\n", doWhileCount);
    }

    doWhileCount = doWhileCount -2;

} while (doWhileCount >= 1);
```